# how to fix SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type Boolean, not type character varying

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql function which uses dynamic sql statements. I have a config table from which i would like to fetch a column in which all the where clause conditions are stored. But while doing so i am getting below error. 
SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type character varying. I tried multiple options but it is throwing the same error again and again.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ech_test.usr_select_tab(p_tabname text)
 RETURNS SETOF record
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$

declare
r record;
l_fields text;

begin

    for r in 

    EXECUTE 
           'SELECT field1, field2'
        || ' FROM '
        || p_tabname::regclass
        || ' WHERE '
        || '( select where_clause from table2 where rule_id is not null)'
 loop
 return  next r;
    end loop;

  return;

end;


$function$
;
```

It shout return the where_clause field from the table2, apply it to the main query and return the resulting rows.

Comment: WHERE requires a conditional statement that results in true or false for selecting table rows. What's the relationship between `table2` and `p_tabname`? Without knowing your schema it's hard to tell what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to concatenate the text in `table2` as a `WHERE` clause, you have to do it when building the query, not in the query itself.

```
       'SELECT field1, field2'
    || ' FROM '
    || p_tabname::regclass
    || ' WHERE '
    || ( select where_clause from table2 where rule_id is not null)
```

Maybe you also want to change that subquery though. You have to make sure, that exactly one row (and one column) is returned. Otherwise you either get an error, that multiple rows aren't allowed here or null the entire string if no row is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just want to check for the existence of a matching record in your `WHERE` clause:

```
EXECUTE 
       'SELECT field1, field2'
    || ' FROM '
    || p_tabname::regclass
    || ' WHERE EXISTS '
    || '( select 1 from table2 where rule_id is not null)'
```

If this doesn't meet your needs, then you may have to deal with the case where the subquery returns more than one record.  Also, the subquery is selecting a column value, which is not necessarily a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first retrieve the condition(s) to be used, store them in a variable and concatenate that variable into your dynamic SQL.

Note, that your query can potentially return more than one row. In that case the SELECT would fail inside the function (or simply use the "first" one returned, depending on your Postgres configuration and version).

The question is: what do you want to do if the query on `table2` returns more than one row? In the code example below, I added a second version which combines all conditions with an `AND` - but that is just a guess. You have to adjust that to match your requirements.

The use of a `for` loop is also unnecessary.

So your function should look something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ech_test.usr_select_tab(p_tabname text)
  RETURNS SETOF record
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS 
$function$
declare
  l_condition text;
  l_sql text;
begin
    -- !!!! this will fail if the query returns multiple rows !!!!
    select where_clause 
      into l_condition
    from table2 where rule_id is not null;

    -- if you want to combine the conditions from table2 then use this:
    select string_agg(where_clause, ' AND ')
       into l_condition
    from table2 where rule_id is not null;

    -- build the complete SELECT query           
    l_sql := format('SELECT field1, field2 FROM %I WHERE %s', p_tabname, l_condition);

    -- and return the result of running that query
    return query execute l_sql;

end;
$function$
;
```